# The LEGO Movie 2: How to unlock Coffee Unchained?

Tags: the-lego-movie-2-videogame

It's fairly straightforward how to clear all the other quests in Apocalypseburg. But this one has me confused.

We have this shop "Coffee Unchained", but it's not obvious how to "unchain" it. Presumably, doing so reveals the final "Master Piece" (purple brick) for Apocalypseburg.

[image: Coffee Unchained]

[From what I've read online](https://forum.psnprofiles.com/topic/72819-help-needed-with-coffee-unchained/), one must build tables and chairs, and then place or equip food.

I've tried this in various combinations, but to no avail. It's not clear which items must be built/equipped.

Having acquired 49 of the 50 possible Master Pieces for this world, it's really irking me.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that Coffee Unchained is actually *not* a quest in Apocalypseburg. Instead, the Apocalypseburg shop where you can buy a Master Piece is the building simply labeled "Shop", North of the Liberty Statue. This is the building onto which you shoot stickers in a side-quest.

[image: Master Piece - Awesome!]
[image: Apocalypseburg Shop]

The page I linked to in my question doesn't specify the world, which caused me some confusion. After checking some guides it became clear.

[This guide to Apocalypseburg](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/ps4/252858-the-lego-movie-2-videogame/faqs/77191/apocalypseburg) mentions nothing about Coffee Unchained. Instead, it is one of the quests *in Syspocalypstar*. According to [the guide to Syspocalypstar](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/ps4/252858-the-lego-movie-2-videogame/faqs/77191/syspocalypstar) one must:

> Speak to the guy in front and he'll ask you to build four "Blue
> Chairs" and two "Outdoor Tables". Next, get him the three items:
> "Donut", "Croissant", and "Pretzel". These can all be bought in
> Classic Bricksburg. Return them to him.

I had assumed there would be a way to eventually unlock Coffee Unchained in Apocalypseburg because it's part of the story of that world, and is featured in the movie as a defining landmark of the city. But in the game it is reserved for later when you build it in Syspocalypstar and it has its own little side-quest there.

In Apocalypseburg, both the Shop and Coffee Unchained are locked the first time you play through. After building a regular shop in Syspocalypstar, the Shop in Apocalypseburg opens up, while Coffee Unchained does not.